# Is it possible to define website variables for git?

Tags: command-line, bash, git

I would like to be able to run something like:

```
git clone mw/Math.git
```

where `mw` equals: `https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions`, i.e., the MediaWiki extensions git repository. Instead of running the full form of this command:

```
git clone https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions/Math.git
```

is there a way to define this variable `mw` such that git understands it?

Comment: Why not put the command in a file and execute the file? Could be "mw" where "./mw" executes it/

Comment: Because the `Math.git` part varies according to the extension I'm downloading.

Comment: Not a problem perse ;) Add a variable to the script so you can do "./mw Math.git" and add that the same way Oli's anwer (ie. something like this  `git clone $MW/$GIT`

Comment: I am by no means a bash expert so I'm curious as to how to create a variable that's provided at the command line that corresponds to the extension's name. I would like to be able to save these definitions in `~/.bashrc`, if it makes a difference. Write up an answer, and at the very least I'll upvote it, but seeing how all I asked in my original question was answered in Oli's answer I'll probably accept his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of, but you could define them as Bash variables:

```
MW="https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions"
git clone $MW/Math.git
```

To make that definition stick, you'd need to lodge it in somewhere like `~/.bashrc` (which runs when each Bash session loads).

---

Rinzwind's idea in the comments is sort of the reverse of mine: create function or script that calls `git` and treat the `Math` as a variable for it. Again, this is something you can just enter into a Bash session and test, and then keep in `~/.bashrc`:

```
function mw {
    git clone https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions/$1.git
}

mw Math
```

Or keep it as a script in `~/bin/mw` (and `chmod +x` it):

```
#!/bin/sh
git clone https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions/$1.git
```

If you have to create `~/bin/` that won't be added to the path until you open a new Bash session.

Comment: Just one last bit of customization I'd like to do, that I need some help with. I have that mw function cding to `/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions` before running, is there a way to get it to cd back to where it was before running the function?

Comment: You can use `pushd <directory>` to change dir and then `popd` to go back. `cd <directory>` and `cd -` also work in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

That seems exactly what a remote does inside a repository:

```
$ git init ttt
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/user/1000/home-tmp/ttt/.git/
$ cd ttt 
$ git remote
$ git remote add mw https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions
$ git remote                                                          
mw
$ git remote --verbose 
mw      https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions (fetch)
mw      https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions (push)
```

But normally, like in this case, remotes are part of a repository configuration.

***Note: the global remote does not work with clone - so it does not really fit the question.***

What you need is a globaly defined remote.
Technically I see no reason against that - and it seems to basically work:

Move the configuration section for a remote created in some (even empty) repository to the global configuration:

Remove the section from `ttt/.git/config`:

```
[remote "mw"]
    url = https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/mw/*

$ git remote --verbose
```

and insert it into `~/.gitconfig`:

```
$ git remote --verbose
mw      https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions (fetch)
mw      https://git.wikimedia.org/git/mediawiki/extensions (push)
```

Comment: Hmm... it sems not to work with clone... May it be helpful to build a similar alternative solution?

Comment: Let me know by votes whether I should keep this answer ;)